# How to copy individual files with Maven Resource Plugin

Tags: javascript, java, maven, build, resources

I know it's possible to copy the content of directory and apply filters, but is it possible to specify individual files *in arbitrary directory* to be copied using Maven Resource Plugin, or should I resort plugins like antrun?

**EDIT:** problem solved, read my answer

Comment: You probably need to elaborate more on what you're trying to do. If you don't want the files copied then don't put them in the src/main/resources directory.

Answer (score 2):

This configuration did it for me

```
<execution>
    <id>copy-html-and-images-to-dist</id>
    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/frontend/dist</outputDirectory>
        <overwrite>true</overwrite>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/frontend/src</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>index.html</include>
                    <include>images</include>
                    <include>favicon.ico</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

Comment: The solution looks wrong, cause i assume you have a war project? Furthermore what is `src/main/frontend/src` for ?

Comment: It is an ear project. frontend/src contains the React UI source code, which webpack bundles into dist folder. I have to copy index.html and images manually there due the poorly configured webpack, but it does the trick. This dist folder is later copied to webapp folder by another plugin execution, before building the ear. I tested it and it works correctly

Comment: You should move the react code to the war module...so you don't need to do this kind of hack..

Comment: We like to keep concerns separated. Anyway some hack is needed to include only the bundled javascript to ear

Comment: In the EAR ? I have my doubts about that. Those things belong to WAR module which you can handle with overlays...